# Data Contract deserialization issue with char - C#

Tags: c#, serialization, datacontractserializer, xmlserializer

my Code reference

```
var sample = DataContractDeserializeObject<MySample>(
                        "<MySample xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Sample\"><Charecter>'D'</Charecter></MySample>");

When i run this code. i get this message "There was an error deserializing the object of type MySample. Content cannot be converted to the type Int. Line 1, position 129."
```

My deserialization code

```
 public static T DataContractDeserializeObject<T>(string objectToDeserialize)
        {
            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(objectToDeserialize)))
            {
                var serializer =
                    new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
                return (T)serializer.ReadObject(reader);
            }
        }
```

My dataContract

```
[DataContract]
    public class MySample
    {
        [DataMember]
        public char Charecter { get; set; }
    }
```

how a char can be deserialized. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I vaguely remember something about chars being serialized into their ascii representation for some reason.  Don't try D, try 104.